# Transparency of back view using XBpageCurl

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0

I am just trying out the dragging example doing little changes, but when back view is showed it looks very light, like faded due to transparency of main view.

```
- (void)refreshPageCurlView
{
    ...
    [pageCurlView drawViewOnFrontOfPage:self.viewToCurl];
    [pageCurlView drawViewOnBackOfPage:self.viewBackToCurl]; //I added this
    ...
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        ...
        [self.pageCurlView drawViewOnFrontOfPage:self.viewToCurl];
        [self.pageCurlView drawViewOnBackOfPage:self.viewBackToCurl]; //I added this
        ...
    }
}
```

The three views are linked and showed in the right place, but back one is faded and I need it 100% opaque.

Any help with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got the solution for this.

if you go to BackFragmentShader.glsl
Swap to commented line with the other.

```
// gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb*(1.0 - gradient.a) + gradient.rgb, color.a); // premultiplied alpha
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, 1.0); // premultiplied alpha
```